# "Backup Failed" after manually deleting old backup files

Tags: 13.04, backup, deja-dup

The Ubuntu backup system was using up too much of my disk space, so I decided to start fresch, and manually remove all existing backup files. But now every time I start the backup process (either by clicking the 'Back Up Now...' button, or by using 'deja-dup --backup' from the CLI, I get a popup window containing this message:

> Specified archive directory
>   '/home/[me]/.cache/deja-dup/7b5f5b35d423174917aee4c3a7052081' does not
>   exist, or is not a directory

```
$ ls -las /home/[me]/.cache/deja-dup/
total 8
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  8 10:46 .
4 drwxrwxr-x 3 arne arne 4096 Dec  8 09:55 ..
```

How do I reset deja-dup? Where is the '7b5f5b35d423174917aee4c3a7052081' information saved?

**[extra info]**

Perhaps I should note that

```
~/.cache/deja-dup
```

is symlinked to a folder on a extra hard drive (/dev/sdb1, ext3) mounted in /media/WD1TB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out

```
~/.cache/deja-dup
```

wasn't writable.

But now I get

```
Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup'...
```

see my new post:

["Backup Failed": Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560339/backup-failed-could-not-restore-cache-deja-dup-metadata-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the UI to do that, but now that you *are* in this situation, a

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge deja-dup
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

should fully reset deja-dup...

However, now that you're uninstalling deja-dup anyway, you might have a look at "[back-in-time](http://backintime.le-web.org/)" as well...  ;-)

Comment: That seems overly complicated, removing and reinstalling... but fine.

Comment: I can also tell you to install `gtkorphan` but as you broke things already, the above is the *safe* option...  :P  ;-)
Oh, and *if* it works, please don't forget to accept my answer and if you really like it, upvote as well! :)

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `/home/<me>/.cache/deja-dup` and `/home/<me>/.cache/duplicity` and that seemed to reset things. Now it is going ahead and made a new backup.