# "Backup Failed": Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup

Tags: 14.04, backup, deja-dup

I'm starting backup from the 'Settings' app, clicking the 'Back Up Now...' button. It seems to back up fine, but when it get to 'verifying backup...' the error message shows up:

> Backup Failed.
>
> Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup

It's a fresh backup, only one single directory.

~/.cache/deja-dup is symlinked to a folder on a extra hard drive (/dev/sdb1, ext3) mounted in /media/WD1TB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a known bug in Deja-dup:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1217959

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by simply creating a metadata file in .cache/deja-dup
i.e., from the home directory issue the terminal command

```
touch .cache/deja-dup/metadata
```

dejadup-preferences is still throwing CRITICAL errors but probably unrelated to this.